# How to do switching noise analysis of dcdc on LTSpice

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, ltspice

**Background** : In one of my board i have used LT8471 as DCDC , as my cards being analog cards, i tried maximum to seperate the power network and analog chain from noise, my initial problems with dc-dc noise are answered here at [Apporach1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300498/eliminating-those-unwanted-op-amptia-outputs)  and [Approach2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302052/best-way-to-filter-dc-dc-output-noise) after which i have curbed the noise to <100mV by incorporating CLC pi filters at dcdc output

**Problem** :
still i see some spurious switching noise pulses appearing in my analog channel , in order to completely eliminate switching noise , i wish to do noise analysis like we do with case of opamps, similary i want to measure the switching noise on LTSpice and then apply correct combination of pi filters to eliminate them

below is the the schematic of IC i am using, i have just added a CLC pi filter at the output where L is a 10uH and C being combination of 1nF,100nF,47uF

[image]

Comment: Just look at the spectrum of the output voltage?

Comment: @PlasmaHH , usual simulation wont show a switching noise, it just shows the ramp up of voltage and it attaining a stable voltage output,  but not  switching noise

Comment: How low is the ESR of those 47uF? Should be <0.01 Ohm at least. Curious, did you consider using a LDO linear reg after the switcher?  For sensitive analog circuitry, that will likely work better than any amount of filtering.

Comment: @kakeh: have you actually simulated the schematic you are showing?